# Using progressbar in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to update some code that I didn't originally write.

I'm getting an error right out of the gate with ProgressBar, but I can't seem to identify what the problem is.

My code is:

```
Public Function CharStyles() As Dictionary

  Dim CharacterProgress As ProgressBar
  Set CharacterProgress = New ProgressBar

' some more code after this...

End Function
```

Hovering over 'New ProgressBar' - I see the error "ProgressBar =Object variable or With variable not set", but I can seem to find any information on using ProgessBar in VBA to get any understanding of what that error means.

Can anyone help me understand what the issue is here? Presumably this code worked before, so I'm not sure what I'm missing that's causing it to break.

Thank you.

Comment: Word has no easily usable built-in progress bar, so that could be leftover from a plugin or custom code. My guess would be that it's not critical to whatever else the code is supposed to do, so I would `'comment` out all lines that refer the progress bar.  Use CTRL+F to search the `project` for the word progress.  Prior to doing anything, make a second copy of the file. Also I'd suggest you put `Option Explicit` as the first line in the module, to help you identify other issues.

Comment: If you decide you want to add a progress bar back in, there are various methods, all with varying levels of work required.  (But I wouldn't suggest worrying about esthetics at this point.)

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea how they got it to work? I see it’s part of VB. Is there a reference I need to add so that my project can use VB code?